# React.js code not working

Tags: reactjs

i am newbie to react.js and i was going through a tutorial to start with.

I tried both the jsx format and non jsx format code. however i am not getting the output displayed. I checked the console and no errors reported in chrome.

what am i missing here?

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset = "UTF-8">
<title> React.js <title>

<script type="text/javascript" src = "http://fb.me/react-0.12.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "http://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.12.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/jsx">

/*var App = React.createClass(
{
   render:function()
   {
        return <h1> Hello there </h1>
   }

});

React.render(<App />, document.body);*/


</script>

<script>

    var App = React.createClass(
        {
            render: function()
            {
                return React.DOM.h1(null,"Hi  there")
            }
        });

    React.render(App(), document.body);


</script>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have forgotten to close your title tag

Comment: oh! my bad. thx dart programmer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not closing the `title` tag. This: `<title> React.js <title>` should be this: `<title> React.js </title>`. If you change that, the heading renders like it should.